# Pluralization issue on the Ask question's side panel on the right-hand side

Tags: bug, asking-questions, plurals

There is a *pluralization* issue on the *Ask question*'s side panel on the right-hand side.

When you have one issue to be resolved on the post, it shows a warning as:

> Resolve 1 issue**s** before posting

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Review question]